# Optimizing a merge sort

Tags: python, sorting

I need to optimize my sort (a merge sort), so that with a list of size 10^6 will be sorted in less than 100 seconds. My best time at the moment is 105 seconds and I can't think of a way to make this code more optimized.

```
def my_sort(lst):
if len(lst) > 1:
    puolivali = len(lst) // 2
    vas = lst[:puolivali]
    oik = lst[puolivali:]
    vas = my_sort(vas)
    oik = my_sort(oik)
    lst = []
    while len(vas) > 0 and len(oik) > 0:
        if vas[0] < oik[0]:
            lst.append(vas[0])
            vas.pop(0)
        else:
            lst.append(oik[0])
            oik.pop(0)

    for i in vas:
        lst.append(i)
    for i in oik:
        lst.append(i)

return lst
```

Comment: @Toppe--the [time complexity of your pop operations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) is O(N) which is expensive.  Other merge sort algorithms, [such as](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/), don't involve pop(0).

Comment: `vas.pop(0)` and `oik.pop(0)` are shifting all remaining elements on every pass, which makes iterating through them `O(n**2)` in total, and the complexity of your sort `O(n**2 log n)` instead of the expected `O(n log n)`. You can try reversing the sublists and popping from the end, which is O(1), [like this](https://pastebin.com/nJXJ4Mvk).

Comment: @DarrylG Ugh, the second Python solution there does `pop(0)` as well. geeksforgeeks really is the worst site ever. Maybe the OP actually got it from there, it seems to be the exact same code except for renamed variables.

Comment: @user4815162342 Complexity of their sort is O(n**2).

Comment: @superbrain--thanks, I only saw the first solution which at a glance seemed okay.  Agree the second solution is not a reasonable alternative except for a learning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.pop(0)` is the main performance killer as it shifts all subsequent elements. Use a moving index instead:

```
    # ...
    vas_i = oik_i = 0
    lst = []
    while vas_i < len(vas) and oik_i < len(oik):
        if vas[vas_i] < oik[oik_i]:
            lst.append(vas[vas_i])
            vas_i += 1
        else:
            lst.append(oik[oik_i])
            oik_i += 1

    lst.extend(vas[vas_i:])
    lst.extend(oik[oik_i:])
```

Or as a complete function:

```
def my_sort(lst):
    mid = len(lst) // 2
    if mid:
        lo, hi = my_sort(lst[:mid]), my_sort(lst[mid:])
        lo_i = hi_i = 0
        lst = []
        while lo_i < len(lo) and hi_i < len(hi):
            if lo[lo_i] > hi[hi_i]:
                lo, lo_i, hi, hi_i = hi, hi_i, lo, lo_i
            lst.append(lo[lo_i])
            lo_i += 1
        lst.extend(lo[lo_i:])
        lst.extend(hi[hi_i:])
    return lst
```

Comment: You could extend by `lo[lo_i:] or hi[hi_i:]` to save yet another line.